# Can't compile this command (Java and Ant related)

Tags: java, ant

basically, I am following steps on my exercises and I cannot seem to get this command to run properly. I tried to change something, but it doesn't work. Here's an example of what I have to execute:

```
C:\Users\Bill\My Documents\Antbook\ch04>javac -d build\test test\org\example\antbook\junit\SimpleTest.java
```

This does not run properly. I have created those files already, but it doesn't execute.

Heres, the error i get:

```
javac: not a directory: build\test
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Any suggestions? I am assuming there's something wrong with the command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> javac: not a directory: build\test

Sounds like build\test doesn't exist.  Try creating that directory first.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Got it compiled, but now i have a problem with: test\org\example\antbook\junit\SimpleTest.java:4: error:package org.junit does not exist import static org.junit.Assert.*;

Comment: Feel so stupid not to notice that. Been having a stressful day with these exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Is your directory called `test test`?
If so, your problem is the space in between, you should add `"` quotes for this cases.
Try this:

```
javac -d "build\test test\org\example\antbook\junit\SimpleTest.java"
```

or

```
javac -d build\"test test"\org\example\antbook\junit\SimpleTest.java
```

As long as the white spaces in directory names are between `"` any is fine, you could even use this: `TESTE~1`, instead of the full directory name, but that's way too bothersome >_<

Comment: I don't think it's a whitespace issue.  He is using the -d option to specify a directory (build\test) to put the outputted class files.

Comment: Oh... so that's what the -d does